# c++ enable accessibility inspection in Google Chrome

Tags: c++, google-chrome, uiaccessibility

I'm trying to access text of Google Chrome's webpage to read it and offer some actions (for example, remind). Everything works good, but I need to enable accessibility inspection programmatically. I use this code:

```
wchar_t className[100];
GetClassName(hwnd, className, 100) == 0 || wcscmp(className, L"Chrome_WidgetWin_1");

CComPtr<IAccessible> pAccMain;
HRESULT hr = ::AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hWndChrome, 1, IID_IAccessible, (void**)(&pAccMain));

CComPtr<IAccessible> pAccMain2;
::AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hWndChrome, OBJID_CLIENT, IID_IAccessible, (void**)(&pAccMain2));
```

And nothing happens until I run browser with *--force-renderer-accessibility* parameter or manually change accessibility settings located in *chrome://accessibility*.

What am i doing wrong?

Found this info: "Chrome calls NotifyWinEvent with EVENT_SYSTEM_ALERT and the custom object id of 1. If it subsequently receives a WM_GETOBJECT call for that custom object id, it assumes that assistive technology is running". Does anybody know how to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [SetWinEventHook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwineventhook), e.g.

```
HWINEVENTHOOK hook = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_SYSTEM_ALERT, EVENT_SYSTEM_ALERT,NULL, WinEventProc, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT)
```

Then in your WinEventProc, you'll be given a hWnd, idObject, and idChild when Chrome sends the EVENT_SYSTEM_ALERT.

If `idObject == 1` then call [AccessibleObjectFromEvent()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/oleacc/nf-oleacc-accessibleobjectfromevent), passing it those hWnd, idObject, and idChild arguments.

AccessibleObjectFromEvent will then send the WM_GETOBJECT. [From the docs:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winauto/wm-getobject):

> Applications never send this message directly. Microsoft Active Accessibility sends this message in response to calls to AccessibleObjectFromPoint, AccessibleObjectFromEvent, or AccessibleObjectFromWindow.

By using AccEvent I can see that Google Chrome only appears to send the EVENT_SYSTEM_ALERT when it starts, e.g. opening a new tab doesn't trigger it, so you'd need to have done the SetWinEventHook() before Chrome is launched.